# Redirecting method's super for mixins in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**Question**

So I've figured out (for some reason) a method's super variable is set in stone the first time a script is run, meaning if you assign the method to another object with a different **proto** the method will still call the base class on the original object.

The only way I can see to get around this is to use eval to reinstantiate the method on another object, but that won't work because I don't have access to the original scope that the class was defined in, meaning includes and referenced variables would cause errors.

Annoyingly Object.defineProperty doesn't fix this either.

Essentially I'm looking for a way to duplicate a function, so that on the duplicate the [[HomeObject]] is set to my new prototype object.

**[Edit]: More Information**

The plan is to have this sort of prototype chain

```
A - "static" class
B - "static" class, extends from A
MixC(B) - a prototype object, which is cloned and has B set as the prototype of the clone
D - a "static" class that extends from MixC(B)

X - "static" class, extends from A
MixC(X)  - a prototype object, which is cloned and has X set as the prototype of the clone
Y - a "static" class that extends from MixC(X)
```

The actual code for duplicating this and resolving pretty much everything works just fine, the only problem I'm having is that I can't change the [[HOMEOBJECT]] of the functions decided on the MixC object to point to whatever class is the parent when I'm cloning MixC. As MixC is defined as a class that extends A, super in the functions defined on MixC will always refer to A regardless of what object the functions are assigned to.

The only way I've found to change the [[HOMEOBJECT]] is to change the prototype of MixC to something other than A, but because MixC can be mixed into multiple things at the same time, nothing I set it to will work for all uses.

**Background**

I have an extensive project going on in which I decided to use mixins to solve a problem with exponential code growth. My implementation of mixins creates a new prototype chain that includes the mixin and the base class that can then be instantiated (using Reflect) all of this is the closest thing to compile-time mixins or multiple inheritance that you can get in javascript. It's been working well, so this error was rather out-of-the-blue. I don't know if I'm doing something new or chrome has changed in a way that has made this no longer possible.

I am not using any 3rd party library that supports "mixins" those libraries usually have significant limitations like not being able to mix a mixin into something that's already been mixed, or they're only available for jsx (which I'm not using) or they require me changing languages (I'm using typescript).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *"... My implementation of mixins creates a new prototype chain ..."*. I start feeling nervous, if any kind of implementation that fiddles around with `prototype`(s) is referred to or even directly named *mixin*. The entire purpose of a mixin is to shift code-reuse away from inheritance (prototype).

Comment: Well unfortunately javascript doesn't do so well with not messing with the prototype chain, because name conflicts for functions and variables become a really big problem (often the mixin wants to call the original code on the base class). Also Typescript's built-in "solution" to mixins uses prototype inheritance, so that's where I got the idea from. It's just that Typescript's way of doing it makes typing a nightmare and disables a bunch of built-in javascript capabilities, for example it breaks instanceof.

Comment: If one refers to the concepts of *Mixin* and *Inheritance* then it is never a good idea to intermingle mixin with the latter. Each has its own way of how code reuse gets accomplished. Thus, also in JS, any mixin implementation should never rely on or touch the prototype(inheritance) in order to establish code reuse. This is not just a strong opinion. Mixin/trait based ***object/type composition*** and ***inheritance*** are totally distinct. A bad example are *class based JS mixins*. The result is always a class, created instantly by a class-factory. They always extend each other(inheritance).

Comment: What is the meaning and the purpose of what you refer to as *"static" class*? Something like ... it never is allowed to be instantiated directly (no direct construct) but are allowed to extend another class?

Comment: @PeterSeliger static was the wrong word, but I was struggling for a good one. It's the closest I can get to a compile-time class (not modified at run-time). This is necessary for it to operate well with Typescript.

Comment: As per your other comment, that is in fact, your opinion.The mixin pattern doesn't specifically declare that you can't alter the prototype chain: "Mixin programming is a style of software development, in which units of functionality are created in a class and then mixed in with other classes." (it's just that usually it doesn't).

Comment: If Microsoft, one of the largest, most prolific software companies in the world, along with the ESNext council which includes developers from chrome, node, firefox and other large prolific software companies decide that mixins can alter prototypes (when I add, the definition of mixin doesn't specifically preclude this) then what credentials do you have to back up that that is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, or will be possible, because this very thing was actually discussed and rejected on the esdiscuss forums:

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/any-tomethod-use-case

There was a function called toMethod that was specifically proposed for solving multiple inheritance problems (which was essentially what I was trying to do) by changing the [[HOMEOBJECT]] of a method (through duplicating the method) but was rejected due to the implementation expected to be buggy without enough of a payoff. There is now no way to duplicate a method, which would be required to change it's hidden property [[HOMEOBJECT]].

A work-around that's been proposed both on those forums and elsewhere is to assign property to the class that points to the prototype of the parent class and access that for calling functions, rather than using the super keyword. I do not know if this introduces new bugs yet (like what if the function isn't defined on the direct parent), but it seems to be the only option.

Comment: You are most probably looking for ***Trait*** (and no, not necessarily for trait.js). In addition to the basic mixin concept where each of a target type's property will be overwritten by the identically named property of the mixin (source), the concept of ***Traits*** offers abstraction and processes/operations of how to deal in a fine grained way with conflict resolution on an individual base. If you are interested, I could provide some deep dive examples as another answer in addition to your's.

Comment: Does that have anything to do with changing the [[HomeObject]] or are you suggesting it as a better pattern name than Mixin?

Comment: 1/2 Almost both. Mixin and [Trait](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/traits) implementations in JavaScript that do not directly interfere with the `prototype` are, in my opinion, cleaner, thus less painful to handle, thus better.

**Being agnostic to inheritance** (chains) enables code reuse directly at object level. Thus, due to this flexibility, **such a [unit of code reuse](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/bifrost/talents) can be _applied_ to any kind of object at any state/time of object creation**. It also provides more control over where and when e.g. your [[HomeObject]] can/will be changed.

Comment: 2/2 And as I said, the concept of *Trait* differs from the *Mixin* one by additionally provided operations/processes (like `before`, `after`, `around`, `alias`) for conflict resolution of equally named methods at a trait's *apply time*.

Comment: 1/2 The main reason I went with the prototype route was the fact that I could get typing for it within the class itself. I have the following pattern: Class A, Mixin Z, Class B extends Z.mix(A). I can now call Z's functions within the class declaration of B. This is why I wanted to use prototype mixins, not just because I needed them on the final object but because I needed their type-safety at compile time.

Comment: 2/2 Afaik short of monkey-patching methods onto the parent class' prototype that's not possible with non-prototype mixins. Since I don't want Z mixed in to all of A's uses  I can't modify A's prototype. If I didn't have these requirements then I probably would have done it your way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really like to see some more implementation specific details from all the classes and *class syntax based "mixins"*, especially the parts that just want to use some (prototypal ?) methods of a class' implementation.

Such information was really important for choosing the most fitting approach, otherwise one mostly has the chance of guessing.

This is, what I came up with from the OP's last comments and the original question's pseudo code block, mainly in order to gain an understanding of the discussed matter (for both/all sides) ...

```js
// class A module.
class A {
  constructor(foo, bar, baz) {
    // public properties.
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = baz;
  }
  // prototypal getter methods.
  getFoo() {
    console.log('this.foo :', this.foo);
  }
  getBar() {
    console.log('this.bar :', this.bar);
  }
  getBaz() {
    console.log('this.baz :', this.baz);
  }
}
/*export A;*/


// mixin module: withZ.

// module scope.
function getBizz() {
  console.log('this.bizz :', this.bizz);
}
function getBooz() {
  console.log('this.booz :', this.booz);
}
// function based mixin.
/*export */function withZ() {
  this.getBizz = getBizz;
  this.getBooz = getBooz;
  return this;
};


// mixin module: with Z and getBaz behavior from class A.

const prototypalGetBaz = A.prototype.getBaz;

// function based mixin compound.
/*export */function withZAndGetBazBehavior(...args) {
  withZ.apply(this, args);
  this.getBaz = prototypalGetBaz;
}

// "mixin" class ZAndGetBaz which does not implement anything
// type specific but instead just augments its `prototype`.
class ZAndGetBaz {}
withZAndGetBazBehavior.call(ZAndGetBaz.prototype);
/*export ZAndGetBaz;*/


// class B module which does extend a class which itself
// does not implement anything type specific but
// does feature an augmented  `prototype`.

class B extends ZAndGetBaz {
  constructor(baz, bizz, booz) {
    super();
    this.baz = baz;
    this.bizz = bizz;
    this.booz = booz;
  }
}
/*export B;*/


// class C module which does not extend but directly
// mixes/applies all bahvior into/to its `prototype`.

class C {
  constructor(baz, bizz, booz) {
    this.baz = baz;
    this.bizz = bizz;
    this.booz = booz;
    // // apply mixin either at construction/instantiation time ...
    // withZAndGetBazBehavior.call(C.prototype);
  }
}
// ... or apply additional behavior directly to the prototype object.
withZAndGetBazBehavior.call(C.prototype);
/*export C;*/


// test module.

const a = new A('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
const b = new B('myBaz', 'myBizz', 'myBooz');
const c = new C('yourBaz', 'yourBizz', 'yourBooz');

console.log('(a instanceof A) ?', (a instanceof A));
console.log('\n');

console.log('(b instanceof B) ?', (b instanceof B));
console.log('(b instanceof A) ?', (b instanceof A));
console.log('(b instanceof ZAndGetBaz) ?', (b instanceof ZAndGetBaz));
console.log('\n');

console.log('(c instanceof C) ?', (c instanceof C));
console.log('\n');

console.log('a.getFoo() ...');a.getFoo();
console.log('a.getBar() ...');a.getBar();
console.log('a.getBaz() ...');a.getBaz();
console.log('\n');

console.log('b.getBaz() ...');b.getBaz();
console.log('b.getBizz() ...');b.getBizz();
console.log('b.getBooz() ...');b.getBooz();
console.log('\n');

console.log('c.getBaz() ...');c.getBaz();
console.log('c.getBizz() ...');c.getBizz();
console.log('c.getBooz() ...');c.getBooz();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

My personal preference is to always favor the function based mixin approach (the example code's `class C`) for it is always easy to come up with reusable code which does glue together use case specific behavior (and even state and then even encapsulated one).

***Opinion ...***

The example of the `class B` implementation which `extends` a so called *class based "mixin"* just proves in my eyes that such a pattern is not only of no additional use in JavaScript, it is even contradicting. A language whose core features are objects, closures and delegation (an automatic / implicit delegation mechanism via prototype chain, hence *inheritance* and *"is a/of type"* relationship ... and explicit delegation via `call`/`apply`, hence *composition via function based mixins* and *"has a behavior"* relationship) carries a natural predisposition for a broader variety of also much more flexible mixin concepts directly at object level (including applying a mixin to a `prototype` object). ***The implementation*** of a mixin in JavaScript ***should never directly touch inheritance*** (the prototype chain) which it immediately does if written as `class` (and later used via `extends`).

Comment: So using your code to illustrate the problem, if you do:
`function getBizz() {
  super.getFoo();
}` It will error because getBizz is not allowed to have super because it's not part of an object. I wanted it so that getBizz's super call would call A's or C's function depending on which class it was mixed in to, unfortunately that requires duplicating getBizz every time you assign it to a prototype and the problem with *that* is that I can't get typing information from it automatically.

Comment: Now we might have reached a point where it was most helpful to have a boiled down example (JS class syntax preferably) of exactly that kind of inheritance/mixin approach you are struggling with. Trying to (re)create your scenario even from the last comment above leaves me puzzled about both the usage of inheritance within the project and the role of a construct which gets referred to as mixin. But I'm always curious about the many different ways people come up with in order to establish their preferred type system.